# Best Place To Post Tutorial Announcement

Tags: documentation

[I made a tutorial](https://github.com/johnshearing/IOTA-Airgapped-NodeJS-Console-Wallet) for working with IOTA at the BASH console running NodeJS scripts.
Can someone please tell me the best places to anounce the tutorial and also the best places to ask for people examine it for errors?
Thanks

Comment: I would post it on Reddit. Not sure if it is the "best" place, though.

Comment: Thanks @mihi. I will sign up for an account and make the announcement. The help you have given me made the tutorial possible. I hope others will find it useful.